# Contingency table with 2 different time series

Tags: time-series, self-study, contingency-tables

I am trying to put the two time series of my Excel spreadsheet (see link below), into a contingency table.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2f96oylxj97fuih/example.xls

The first series is the number of subscriptions per hour for 24 hours. The second series consists of the hours when ads for different radios stations have been displayed (e.g. ad for Channel 1 at 2:00PM).

I have doubts about the feasibility of putting these 2 time series into a contingency table. Is this reasonable?

Comment: After some additional thoughts, I changed the configuration of the 2 time series but I still have doubt 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lvkku670tgg1b3a/ex_2.xls

Comment: Thanks for the amendments. It is improving the precision of my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this late date it's not likely that answers will be obtained for any of these observations and queries.

A media analyst would instantly recognize the "dependent" vs "independent" nature of the information, i.e., subscriptions are dependent on radio advertising. That analyst would also know that advertising is typically sold by the daypart, defined roughly as fringe (12 am to 6 am), early morning (6 am to 10 am), daytime (10 am to 3 pm), and so on. So, collapsing hourly information to the daypart would be useful.

Key pieces of information are missing from the description. E.g., no time frame is given for this data. Is it for a single day? Is it aggregated over multiple days? Is it a time series? What's the duration or span of time? Given answers to these very basic concerns, considerations such as ad weight, flighting, pricing, seasonality as well as the editorial environment of the radio stations' audience could potentially be evaluated for their impact on subscriptions.

Another consideration is the unit of analysis for the advertising. Is it dollars spent? CPM (cost per thousand listeners reached)? Etc.

Also highly relevant is the radio station where the ads were aired. These are likely to be distributed by region (maybe, maybe not) but based on the description, it sounds like the subscription information is aggregated and not available at a regional level. This would mandate also aggregating the advtg information up from the station level.

These are a few considerations that would complicate putting this information into a single "contingency table." However, multiple tables are possible breaking out the data temporally, regionally, by station, etc.

In addition, appropriate predictive models could be built as a function of the framing of the information which would predict subscriptions by daypart and any other relevant factor. The output from these models could then be represented, maybe not as a contingency table, but certainly as a pivot table comparing predicted with actual subscriptions as a function of these underlying factors.

Comment: Many thanks @DJohnson for your answer. I'm no longer part of the company I worked for. However, I still welcome your answer as it can be still very relevant but in a different manner.

Comment: @AndyK  Wow! I'm impressed with your quick response despite having posted this question 3 years ago. I'm glad the observations made are useful.

Comment: I do care about questions I'm asking, 3 years after or longer or 1mn after and especially, I do care about the answers I'm receiving. Nothing is lost , everything is transformed

Answer (score 0):

After much thinking and much asking around, the only sensible answer is that we cannot have a contingency table as we have TWO time series.

I hope it helps all the learner in stats.